# eval function not working in ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, eval

So I am using ajax to post a serialised form to a php script and then on success alert the returned data.
My code works fine on my local environment, but uploaded, the eval() function mucks everything up.

here is my code:

```
function post_that_shit(formIdToSerialize, postUrl) {
    var serializedData = $("#"+formIdToSerialize).serialize();
    var post_url = postUrl+".php";
    //alert(serializedData + "\n" + post_url);


    $.ajax({
        url: post_url,
        type: "POST",
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(data){
            data = eval('('+data+')' );
            console.log(data.msg);

            if(data.reload == 'yes'){
                window.location.reload();
            }
            if(data.relocate != 'no'){
                window.location.href = data.relocate;
                //alert(data.relocate);
            }
            if(data.msg != 'no'){
                $(".message").html(data.msg);
                //alert(data.msg);
            }

            //alert('relocate: '+data.relocate);
        }
    });


}
```

So it is pretty simple.
The php echo out a json encoded array like so:

```
 echo json_encode(array('msg' => $errors, 'relocate' => 'no'));
```

And depending on what is echoed, the msg is displayed or the user relocated.

Why do I get the error of SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' when I use the code online?
Locally it works just fine :(

Thanx for your help

Chris

Comment: I don't get why you would need to use this eval. can't you just use `data` directly?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe obviously someone mislead him thinking that eval was cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `eval` is evil. Don't use it... never ever! It's like a bomb ready to detonate.

Secondly, parsing json can be done natively in Javascript. No need for `eval`.

You can use `JSON.parse` and it will return you an object parsed by the string containing the json text.

`eval` is used to evaluate code, in other words, it is executing javascript not json. When `eval` returns an object, it is simply a side effect of JSON being a subset of JavaScript. In other words, any string formatted as json can be evaluated to JavaScript. But JavaScript cannot be formatted to JSON. There is no representation of `Date`, `Function` and many more complex objects. That said, when using `eval`, you're actually executing JavaScript and that is the big problem here. It could execute potentially dangerous code while parsing JSON simply requires parsing data into a data structure and nothing more.

Here more about JSON: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation

So it would allow anyone to add somewhat some javascript that would then get executed by your use of `eval`. It could allow someone to execute code on the browser of other users. It could be used to steal passwords for example or steal any kind of private information that wouldn't be accessible otherwise.

jQuery on the other hand allow you to parse json natively by using the `dataType` attribute as 'json'. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: serializedData,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.msg);
```

Or using JSON.parse

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: "POST",
    data: serializedData,
    success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(data.msg);
```

Also as `charlie` pointed out, parsing by ourselves JSON means that we have to wrap it in a `try catch`, because parsing might fail if the json isn't valid.

But using jQuery gives us a way to handle that easily.

You could rewrite your code such as this:

```
var req = $.ajax({
        url: post_url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: serializedDate
});

req.done(function (data) {
  // Success
});

req.fail(function () {
  // Error something went wrong
});
```

The advantage of using the promise form is that you can chain calls to have clean async code instead of the callback hell and infinite function nesting.

Comment: The advantage of letting jQuery do it is that you don't have to catch parse errors yourself. If there is a parse error it will trigger the ajax error handling callbacks and reject the returned promise

Comment: @charlietfl I'm quite aware of this.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I am getting a JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF when using dataType='json'
Is therefore my json_encode somehow wrong ?

Comment: @Chris apparently it is. Could you paste the actual data you're receiving into the question. As you're using PHP, make sure you're not echoing anything else.

Comment: Ok thank you for all the help, I found out, that, in my php the way I was checking the input fields was muddling up the son object somehow.
So after restructuring the checking process, it now works like a charm
Thank you guys

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `eval()`. Just set the `dataType` option to `'json'` and the data will be internally parsed to an object by jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json',
    data: serializedData,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(typeof data); //  returns "object"
```

In addition setting the proper content type header for `application/json` at server also helps

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need the `eval()` function in that place. It's a wrong coding. Your solution is put the data type to JSON and the ajax function treats automatically as a json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: post_url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: serializedData,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.msg);

        if(data.reload == 'yes'){
            window.location.reload();
        }
        if(data.relocate != 'no'){
            window.location.href = data.relocate;
            //alert(data.relocate);
        }
        if(data.msg != 'no'){
            $(".message").html(data.msg);
            //alert(data.msg);
        }

        //alert('relocate: '+data.relocate);
    }
});
```